# Delphi TFDMemTable, CloneCursor and source table out of sync, unless Refresh is called

Tags: delphi, firedac, fdmemtable

the code i'm working on makes heavy usage of TFDMemTables, and clones of those tables using CloneCursor.

Sometimes, under specific conditions which I am unable to identify, the source table and its clone become out of sync: the data between them may be different, the record count as well.
Calling Refresh on the cloned table puts things back in order.

From my understanding, CloneCursor is used to address the same underlying memory where data is stored, meaning alterations to the underlying data from any of the two pointers should reflect on the other table, yet allow the user to have separate filter / record positioning per "view". so how can it possibly go out of sync?

I built a small simulator, where I can insert / delete / filter records in either the table or its clone, and observe the impact on the other one. Changes were reflected correctly.

Another downside of Refresh is that it slows the execution tremendously, if overused.

Has anyone faced similar issues or found explanations / documentation regarding this matter?

Edit:

to clarify what I mean by "out of sync", it means reading a value from the table using FieldByName will return X prior to Refresh, and Y post-refresh. I was not able to reproduce this behavior on the simulator mentioned above.

Comment: That's a lot of questions!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "out of sync" and how it manifests itself in your app.

Comment: technically, 2 questions (there are 2 question marks)
the rest is statements, observations and results of experiments, else the post would face the "what have you tried?" dilemma :)

Comment: @MartynA clarifications added

Comment: Thanks.  My understanding, I think, is pretty much the same as yours, i.e. that a cloned cursor may given you a different "view" of the same data records, in terms of which ones are visible, their order, which record is active, etc, but the two cursors should give the same field values for the same record.  So, if you are finding that the values in fact differ, something is amiss.  I would start by checking for a good, old-fashioned memory overwrite ,y burning the memory manager's FullDebugMode on.  Obs w/o a reproducible prob, readers can't help.  Good luck!

Comment: Made any progress?

Comment: not yet unfortunately, I found a workaround that gets me going, but have not uncovered the core reason yet.